# Retrieve sent message with EWS Managed API

Tags: vb.net, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I'm trying to send a message using EWS Managed API, and I need to confirm message was sent and register some info (ex. the date & time it was sent). However, I get an exception as shown below. My question is: how can I retrieve the `EmailMessage` object for the sent message, after it was sent?

Thank you very much!

```
Private Sub NovaMensagemToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NovaMensagemToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Dim em As New EmailMessage(serviceClient.Service)
    em.Subject = "Test"
    em.Body = "This is a test."
    em.ToRecipients.Add("mytestmail@test.com")
    em.SendAndSaveCopy(WellKnownFolderName.SentItems)
    em.Load() 'Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: This operation can't be performed because this service object doesn't have an Id.
    MsgBox(em.DateTimeSent)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, all it takes is to save a draft before sending:

```
Private Sub NovaMensagemToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NovaMensagemToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Dim em As New EmailMessage(serviceClient.Service)
    em.Subject = "Test"
    em.Body = "This is a test."
    em.ToRecipients.Add("mytestmail@test.com")
    em.Save(WellKnownFolderName.Drafts) '<--- added this
    em.SendAndSaveCopy(WellKnownFolderName.SentItems)
    em.Load() 'no exception now
    MsgBox(em.DateTimeSent)
End Sub
```